# Find and kill bash command variables loading on terminal open MACOSX

Tags: bash, terminal

My terminal opens with a bunch of information with ++ prepended to it. I am trying to find where the command is coming from, and end the command. I believe there may be some restoration of a prior bash session which may be causing the error. Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated.

my /.bash_profile :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

my /.bashrc:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

In the following output I replaced my actual user name with `my_name`.

```
+ '[' -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ']'
++ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
+ eval 'PATH="/usr/bin:/bin";' export 'PATH;'
++ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
++ export PATH
+ '[' /bin/bash '!=' no ']'
+ '[' -r /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' -z '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
++ shopt -s checkwinsize
++ '[' -r /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal ']'
++ . /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
+++ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+++ '[' -n 6F72F67A-7637-4776-A0DA-6AE45A854698 ']'
+++ '[' '!' -e /Users/my_name/.bash_sessions_disable ']'
+ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
+ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
-bash: /Users/my_name/.bash_profile: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: /Users/my_name/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error near `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
-bash: /Users/my_name/.bash_profile: line 3: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=m
++ [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=m
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=t
++ [[ t =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=t
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=t
++ [[ t =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=t
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=h
++ [[ h =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=h
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=w
++ [[ w =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=w
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=d
++ [[ d =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=d
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=t
++ [[ t =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=t
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=h
++ [[ h =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=h
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=g
++ [[ g =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=g
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 24 ))
```

Comment: Have a look at the file `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. Is there a `set -x`? If yes, remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the message! Unfortunately, no "set -x"or any "set" information within rvm.

Comment: Output of the form  `++ something` is caused by a `set -x`, `bash -x`, or something of that form somewhere. You have to find and remove it. However, the output says `/Users/my_name/.bash_profile: line 3` even though you posted a `.bash_profile` with only one line. Are you sure you posted the whole file?

Comment: Thanks for the message, only one line in bash_profile, just two lines after.